# Как написать правильно "Направляем для использования в работе График выполнения работ"?

Tags: стилистика

"Направляем для использования в работе График выполнения работ"

Comment: Чего хочет отправитель - для справки чей-то график предоставить или потребовать от работников соблюдения отправляемого графика?

Answer (score 0):

Направляем для использования в работе форму Графика выполнения работ.